# Sort by group in a table that join with another

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I have 2 tables, where one is lookup table while the other is a transaction log.

```
Lookup table User: UserId, Name and Department.
Transaction log table EntryLog:  LogID, UserId, TimeIn, TimeOut
```

I am trying to retrieve a report to view the last seen time (TimeIn or TimeOut) of ALL the User (which is unique) in the User table.

I tried the follow query but doesn't seen to work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (A.UserID), TimeIn, TimeOut, B.Name, B.Department FROM EntryLog A
  INNER JOIN User B ON B.UserId = A.UserId
  ORDER BY TimeOut DESC, TimeIn DESC
```

Somehow the result seem to retrieve all the records from the transaction Log (including repeated UserId). I am not good in SQL statement and being searching for similar issue without avail.
Any advise is much appreciated. Thank You in advance.

Comment: Your problem arises from the misconception that `DISTINCT` is a function. It isn't. It is applied to the whole rows of the result set, removing duplicate rows.

Answer (score 1):

`Distinct` does not only filters out the `UserId` but every duplicate row.

You want to `GROUP BY UserID` instead. If you're using SQL-Server >= 2005, you can use a CTE with ROW_NUMBER function:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT A.UserID, TimeIn, TimeOut, B.Name, B.Department 
      , ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY UserID Order By Timeout DESC, TimeIn Desc)AS RN
   FROM EntryLog A INNER JOIN User B ON B.UserId = A.UserId 
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use GROUP BY to group by user id and HAVING clause with MAX for TimeIn and TimeOut.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
SELECT  a.UserID, b.TimeIN, b.TimeOut,
        a.Name, a.Department
FROM    Usertable a
            INNER JOIN logTable b
                ON a.userID = b.userid
            INNER JOIN
            (
                SELECT      UserID, MAX(TimeIN) as maxTimeIN
                FROM        logTable
                GROUP BY    UserID
            ) c ON b.userID = c.userID AND
                   b.TimeIN = c.MaxTimeIN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP BY` clause instead of using `DISTINCT` because `DISTINCT` will remove duplicate rows not duplicate column. You can do something like this:

```
SELECT A.UserID, TimeIn, TimeOut, B.Name, B.Department FROM EntryLog A
INNER JOIN User B ON B.UserId = A.UserId
GROUP BY A.UserID, TimeIn, TimeOut, B.Name, B.Department
ORDER BY TimeOut DESC, TimeIn DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT A.UserID, TimeIn, TimeOut, B.Name, B.Department 
FROM EntryLog A INNER JOIN User B ON B.UserId = A.UserId 
where A.LogID in (select MAX(LogID) from EntryLog group by USERID)
```